# 'ServiceController' does not contain a definition for 'GetServices'

Tags: c#, servicecontroller

I what to list all services on my computer with a C# form APP.
But when i follow what all answers to list all services say i get:

`'ServiceController' does not contain a definition for 'GetServices'`

All my research leads to:

```
using ServiceStack.Host;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace myFromApp
{
    public partial class Services : Form
    {
        public Services()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

 private void RefreshServiceBbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
           foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
{
   if (scTemp.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
   {
      //do stuff with each service(display info and such)
  }
}

   }

   }
}
```

`

Comment: `ServiceController.GetServices` exists since .NET FW 1.1. Where is `using System.ServiceProcess`?

Comment: When i add using System.ServiceProces;at the start i get:
The type or namespace name 'ServiceProces' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ygdrazil cause you're missing an s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to import the namespace `System.ServiceProcess` and then you can call `ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();` to obtain the list of services.